# How to set Chrome browser image as wallpaper in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, desktop-customization

I want to set an image in Chrome browser as desktop wallpaper without explicitly downloading the image. Something like http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31759/how-to-set-an-image-as-wallpaper-in-google-chrome/ How can I do that?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score -1):

Hold the picture that you want for a couple seconds then some thing will pop up then the bottom of it will have set as wallpaper